# how to set font awesome icon in input tag

Tags: html, css

Here is the code of input tag and icon:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Username" id="tutu" required />
```

#### CSS

```css
#tutu{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px silver solid;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #bcbcbc;
    height: 40px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: <input type="email" placeholder="Username" id="txtu" required />            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

Comment: Try `<input  type="email" placeholder="Username" id="txtu" class="fa fa-user" required />`

Comment: no it's not working i am using <span class="fa fa-user"></span> and i use the id in input tag so, i can't use class in input tag again

Comment: Wait, you want in in the placeholder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get font awesome icon into input type text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566192/how-to-get-font-awesome-icon-into-input-type-text)

Comment: yes i want placeholder and icon both in one input tag

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder

Comment: Possible duplicate of... it's also do not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a Font Awesome icon to input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988373/how-do-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-input-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the input and icon into a parent div like this

```
<div class="tutuclass">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Username" id="tutu" required />
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</div>
```

Then change the css as follow

```
.tutuclass #tutu{
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px silver solid;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #bcbcbc;
    height: 40px;
    width: 350px;
}
.tutuclass .fa {
    margin: auto -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for Font-awesome icon in placeholder

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type='text' placeholder='&#xf02b; Type any Text'></input>
   </body>     
</html>
```

css code

```
 input {
 padding:10px;
 font-family: FontAwesome, "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login-controls">
  <label> 
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
</div>
```

For css

```
.login-controls{
      margin: 10px 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
      padding: 10px 5px;
}
.login-controls>label{
        width: 10%;
        min-width: 50px;
 }
 .login-controls>input{
        width: 90%;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link. It may helps you need.

**Html Code**

```
<input type="email" placeholder="&#61447; Username" id="tutu" required/>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.wrapper input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}


/* This is for the placeholder */

.wrapper:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  content: "\f007";
}


/* This is for the Textbox */

#tutu {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px silver solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

**Link -** [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhavanaditya/gA4rx/1414/)

Answer (score 0):

I think rachmatsasongko answer is almost perfect. The only problem is that the text will run behind the icon, but you can fix this with a piece of extra css

I made a quick fiddle **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rdfsqpx6/1/)**

```css
.tutuclass #tutu{
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px silver solid;
padding-left: 10px;
font-weight: bolder;
color: #bcbcbc;
height: 40px;
width: 350px;
}
.tutuclass .fa {
margin: auto -30px;
color: #fff;
}
input[type="email"] {
background: #000;
padding-right: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="tutuclass">
<input type="email" placeholder="Username" id="tutu" required />
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</div>
```